# Java reserved name compilation

Tags: java

I have seen this cod, why it works please?

```
public void nеw() {
    System.out.println("!?");
}
```

It is compile in java, I think new is a reserved word

Comment: It's a cyrillic е.

Comment: @010000010110111001100100011100 Wow, how did you spot that?

Comment: One of these questions pops up every few weeks.  I think the people who post them think they're asking a clever riddle, haha.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a [cyrillic е](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye_(Cyrillic)), not a [latin e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E). Therefore, it looks like new, but is actually a different method name.

Like [NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27932262/2930268) said, I would recommend reading [is it a good idea to use unicode symbols as java identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793792/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-unicode-symbols-as-java-identifiers)

Answer (score 7):

Look at the [hex dump](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd):

```
$ xxd -g 1 code.java
0000000: 70 75 62 6c 69 63 20 76 6f 69 64 20 6e d0 b5 77  public void n..w
                                                ↑↑ ↑↑                  ↑↑
0000010: 28 29 20 7b 0a 20 20 20 20 53 79 73 74 65 6d 2e  () {.    System.
0000020: 6f 75 74 2e 70 72 69 6e 74 6c 6e 28 22 21 3f 22  out.println("!?"
0000030: 29 3b 0a 7d 0a 0a                                );.}..
```

The "e" is not the Latin "e". It is a [CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0435/index.htm) (U+0435 encoded in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)). Therefore the `nеw` in the code is not the `new` keyword, but is an identifier that happens to *look* like the `new` keyword.

Take a look at [Is it a good idea to use unicode symbols as Java identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793792/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-unicode-symbols-as-java-identifiers)

Comment: That proves what they say about programming languages: "Once they go Latin, ..."