# Comparator with ArrayList-objects with multiple subclasses

Tags: java, swing, return-value, comparator

```
public class WorthComparator implements Comparator<Värdesak> {
    public int compare(Värdesak v1, Värdesak v2) {
        if (v1 instanceof Apparat && v2 instanceof Apparat) {
            return ((Apparat) v1).worth() > ((Apparat) v2).worth() ? 1
                    : ((Apparat) v1).worth() < ((Apparat) v2).worth() ? -1
                            : 0;
        } else if (v1 instanceof Smycke && v2 instanceof Smycke) {
            return ((Smycke) v1).worth() > ((Smycke) v2).worth() ? 1
                    : ((Smycke) v1).worth() < ((Smycke) v2).worth() ? -1
                            : 0;
        } else if (v1 instanceof Aktie && v2 instanceof Aktie) {
            return ((Aktie) v1).worth() > ((Aktie) v2).worth() ? 1
                    : ((Aktie) v1).worth() < ((Aktie) v2).worth() ? -1 : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to compare different objects from an ArrayList to then sort them in my GUI by highest value. Each different object ("Smycke", Aktie, Apparat") is in their own respective subclass which each has a method for estimate their value. "Värdesak" is the superclass.

My problem is that I don't know who I will get a return-statement to this or is there's another smart way to do it?

Comment: It would be cleaner to make them all implement an interface with `worth()`, or have `worth()` as an abstract method in `Värdesak`. Then you could call `worth()` without any casts or `instanceof` checks.

Comment: Note: perhaps one better modifies the `Värdesak` into `Vardesak`. [using unicode is generally not adviseable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793792/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-unicode-symbols-as-java-identifiers).

Comment: @CommuSoft That may be generally advisable, but once you expect readers to make sense of identifiers in Swedish, misspelling the words hardly makes them more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me the design of your code is wrong, or you applying it the wrong way. Since every "Värdesak" is worth something, you can/need to define this method at the `Värdesak` level:

```
public abstract class Värdesak {

    public abstract double worth ();

}
```

And then:

```
public class Apparat extends Värdesak {

    @Override
    public double worth () {
        return 500.0d;
    }

}
```

Or if the price is fixed, you can use a field:

```
public abstract class Värdesak {

    private double value;

    public double worth () {
        return worth;
    }

}
```

Now you can simply use the *dynamic binding* principle:

```
public class WorthComparator implements Comparator<Värdesak> {

    public int compare(Värdesak v1, Värdesak v2) {
        return Double.compare(v1.worth(),v2.worth());
    }

}
```

[`instanceof` calls are in general considered to be a *bad smell*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589590/why-not-use-instanceof-operator-in-oop-design): if you have to use them, there is normally something wrong with the design of your code.

Another advice, please don't use unicode characters in identifiers: use `Vardesak` instead of `Värdesak`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all the good critique. Really appriciate it! I know about the Unicode, and it will defenetely be fixed when I clean the code. Do you mean that a "general" method in the superclass (worth()) that you override would fix my problem?
Thank you

Comment: you should post this as a comment, otherwise people will start downvoting... And yes, a general method will probably solve the problem. From the moment you have to work with instance of, it breaks object-oriented design.

Comment: Thank you for informing me. I'm very much a novice being on StackOverflow. Ok, I'll try my best, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could also let `Värdesak` implement Comparable interface

```
public abstract class Värdesak implements Comparable<Värdesak> {
    //[...] your code
}
```

Now you define `compareTo` for every class extends `Värdesak`

```
public class Smycke extends Värdesak {

    //[...] your code

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Server o) {
        // TODO: your compare logic
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Later you can sort your Värdesaks in this way: `Collections.sort(värdesakList)`

*EDIT: Note, this solution is not so flexible like Comparator pattern.*

Comment: One in general implements a `Comparator` if there are multiple ways to order a list of items. For instance by name, by value, by id-number,...