# Java regular expression to match valid Java identifiers

Tags: java, regex

I need to create a regular expression able to find and get valid identifiers in Java code like this:

```java
int a, b, c;
float d, e;
a = b = 5;
c = 6;
if ( a > b)
{
c = a - b;
e = d - 2.0;
}
else
{
d = e + 6.0;
b = a + c;
}
```

I have tried to add multiple regexes in a single regex, but how can I build a pattern to exclude reserved words?

I tried this regex `^(((&&|<=|>=|<|>|!=|==|&|!)|([-+=]{1,2})|([.!?)}{;,(-]))|(else|if|float|int)|(\d[\d.]))` but it does not work as expected.

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/CmAWtR/1)

In the following picture, how should I match for identifiers?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Java valid identifier is:

1. having at least one character
2. the first character MUST be a letter `[a-zA-Z]`, underscore `_`, or dollar sign `$`
3. the rest of the characters MAY be letters, digits, underscores, or dollar signs
4. reserved words MUST not be used as identifiers
5. *Update*: as single underscore `_` is a keyword [since Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/whatsnew/toc.htm#JSNEW-GUID-825576B5-203C-4C8D-85E5-FFDA4CA0B346)

A naive regexp to validate the first three conditions would be as follows: `(\b([A-Za-z_$][$\w]*)\b)` but it does not filter out the reserved words.

To exclude the reserved words, negative look-ahead `(?!)` is needed to specify a group of tokens that cannot match:
`\b(?!(_\b|if|else|for|float|int))([A-Za-z_$][$\w]*)`:

- Group #1: `(?!(_\b|if|else|for|float|int))` excludes the list of the specified words
- Group #2: `([A-Za-z_$][$\w]*)` matches identifiers.

However, word border `\b` consumes dollar sign `$`, so this regular expression fails to match identifies starting with `$`.
Also, we may want to exclude matching inside string and character literals ("not_a_variable", 'c', '\u65').

This can be done using positive lookbehind `(?<=)` to match a group *before* main expression without including it in the result instead of the word-border class `\b`:
`(?<=[^$\w'"\\])(?!(_\b|if|else|for|float|int))([A-Za-z_$][$\w]*)`

[Online demo for a short list of reserved words](https://regexr.com/5h6rl)

Next, the full list of the Java reserved words is as follows, which can be collected into a single String of tokens separated with `|`.

A test class showing the final pattern for regular expression and its usage to detect the Java identifiers is provided below.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class IdFinder {

    static final List<String> RESERVED = Arrays.asList(
        "abstract", "assert", "boolean", "break", "byte", "case", "catch", "char", "class", "const",
        "continue", "default", "double", "do", "else", "enum", "extends", "false", "final", "finally",
        "float", "for", "goto", "if", "implements", "import", "instanceof", "int", "interface", "long",
        "native", "new", "null", "package", "private", "protected", "public", "return", "short", "static",
        "strictfp", "super", "switch", "synchronized", "this", "throw", "throws", "transient", "true", "try",
        "void", "volatile", "while", "_\\b"
    );

    static final String JAVA_KEYWORDS = String.join("|", RESERVED);

    static final Pattern VALID_IDENTIFIERS = Pattern.compile(
            "(?<=[^$\\w'\"\\\\])(?!(" + JAVA_KEYWORDS + "))([A-Za-z_$][$\\w]*)");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("ID pattern:\n" + VALID_IDENTIFIERS.pattern());

        String code = "public class Main {\n\tstatic int $1;\n\tprotected char _c0 = '\\u65';\n\tprivate long c1__$$;\n}";

        System.out.println("\nIdentifiers in the following code:\n=====\n" + code + "\n=====");

        VALID_IDENTIFIERS.matcher(code).results()
                         .map(MatchResult::group)
                         .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output

```
ID pattern:
(?<=[^$\w'"\\])(?!(abstract|assert|boolean|break|byte|case|catch|char|class|const|continue|default|double|do|else|enum|extends|false|final|finally|float|for|goto|if|implements|import|instanceof|int|interface|long|native|new|null|package|private|protected|public|return|short|static|strictfp|super|switch|synchronized|this|throw|throws|transient|true|try|void|volatile|while|_\b))([A-Za-z_$][$\w]*)

Identifiers in the following code:
=====
public class Main {
    static int $1;
    protected char _c0 = '\u65';
    private long c1__$$;
}
=====
Main
$1
_c0
c1__$$
```

Comment: I thought Java allowed Unicode characters as part of identifiers, i.e. `Jävä' would be a valid identifier?

Comment: @knittl yes, however that question was initially about attempt to detect usual ASCII-based identifiers.  Also [it does not seem to be a good idea to mix in non-ASCII letters into identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793792/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-unicode-symbols-as-java-identifiers) because the code would turn into a nightmare to maintain.